# Issue while wrapping logger in custom class

Tags: python, python-logging

I'm new to python and trying to create wrapper over logging to reuse changes needed to modify formatting etc.

I've written my wrapper class in following way -

```
import logging
import sys
from datetime import datetime

class CustomLogger:
    """This is custom logger class"""
    _format_spec = f"[%(name)-24s | %(asctime)s | %(levelname)s ] (%(filename)-32s : %(lineno)-4d) ==> %(message)s"
    _date_format_spec = f"%Y-%m-%d @ %I:%M:%S %p"

    def __init__(self, name, level=logging.DEBUG, format_spec=None):
        """"""
        self.name        = name
        self.level       = level
        self.format_spec = format_spec if format_spec else CustomLogger._format_spec

        # Complete logging configuration.
        self.logger = self.get_logger(self.name, self.level)

    def get_file_handler(self, name, level):
        """This is a method to get a file handler"""
        today        = datetime.now().strftime(format="%Y-%m-%d")
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler("{}-{}.log".format(name, today))
        file_handler.setLevel(level)
        file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(self.format_spec,
                                                    datefmt=CustomLogger._date_format_spec))
        return file_handler

    def get_stream_handler(self, level):
        """This is a method to get a stream handler"""
        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        stream_handler.setLevel(level)
        stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(self.format_spec,
                                                      datefmt=CustomLogger._date_format_spec))
        return stream_handler

    def get_logger(self, name, level):
        """This is a method to get a logger"""
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.addHandler(self.get_file_handler(name, level))
        # logger.addHandler(self.get_stream_handler(level))
        return logger

    def info(self, msg):
        """info message logger method"""
        self.logger.info(msg)

    def error(self, msg):
        """error message logger method"""
        self.logger.error(msg)

    def debug(self, msg):
        """debug message logger method"""
        self.logger.debug(msg)

    def warn(self, msg):
        """warning message logger method"""
        self.logger.warn(msg)

    def critical(self, msg):
        """critical message logger method"""
        self.logger.critical(msg)

    def exception(self, msg):
        """exception message logger method"""
        self.logger.exception(msg)
```

But when I try to use my *CustomLogger*, nothing goes into the log file.

```
def main():
    """This main function"""
    logger = CustomLogger(name="debug", level=logging.DEBUG)
    logger.info("Called  main")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I do similar thing without class/function wrapper, it works. Not sure where I'm going wrong. Any pointer will help.

**Further update on the question**

After making this (custom_logger.py) as a package and using in actual application (app.py), I'm noticing it always prints custom_logger.py as filename but not app.py.

How to fix this? I'm ok with rewriting the `CustomLogger` class if required.

Answer (score 1):

I missed to do `setLevel()` for the logger. After doing that, problem is resolved. I also added *pid* for the file handler file-name to avoid any future issue with multi-process env.

Let me know if there's anything I can do better here wrt any other potential issues.